# Undefined variable url in vscode anacondapython

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, anaconda

i have created a view in views.py and when i try to add the url i get the error. I am following a tutorial and doing exactly as told.[created view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMxtw.png)

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.http import HttpResponse 
# Create your views here.
 def index(request):
return HttpResponse("Hello World!")
```

[adding url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmcq0.png)

```
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

[tutorial im following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNF6F.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, try to include the code as text in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#url) so that you can use it in your `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url

from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

You should be aware that `url` is the old way of defining url patterns and is likely to be deprecated in the future

Comment: Thank you very much! solved the problem..cant vote because of low reputation